# ComboBox to select only data in the list but submit their 3 digit code HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, autocomplete

I want to add a input box in my form where users can select airport similar to the one in this website (http://www.wego.pk/) Like when you type on the Destination Input, you get a list of possible values with detailed suggestion including city name + country name but when user submits the form the value submitted is the 3 digit code for the airport.

I tried html5 combobox as:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="product" list="productName"/>
    <datalist id="productName">
        <option value="ISB">Pen</option>
        <option value="KHI">Pencil</option>
        <option value="PWH">Paper</option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But if I type Pen then no suggestion comes. Kindly share some code snippet or any library for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend to use an autocomplete plugin (e.g. jQuery UI autocomplete) instead HTML5 datalist. However, if the question is regarding the datalist, you can populate the product code into hidden field:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="productCode" id="productCode" value="">
    <input type="text" name="product" id="product" list="productName" autocomplete="off">
    <datalist id="productName">
        <option data-code="ISB">Pen</option>
        <option data-code="KHI">Pencil</option>
        <option data-code="PWH">Paper</option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    // use "bind" instead "on" with jQuery lt 1.7
    $("#product").on("input", function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var listId = $(this).attr("list");
        var $option = $("#" + listId + " option").filter(function() {
            return ($(this).val() == val);
        });
        var code = ($.type($option.data("code")) != "undefined" ? $option.data("code") : "");
        $("#productCode").val(code);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: datalist is not working on safari browser...!!  How can I populate product code after using jQuery autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Regarding jQuery UI see this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/  Also you may want to check this plugin: http://easyautocomplete.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if this solution could help you but with some jquery you can do this:

```js
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#product').val();
        
        alert($('#productName [value="' + value + '"]').data('value'));
      
      
      
      $('#productId').val($('#productName [value="' + value + '"]').data('value'));
//after this line the form should submit and correct value passes to server but value passes through hidden input 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" />
<input type="text" name="product" id="product" list="productName" />
    <datalist id="productName">
        <option value="Pen" data-value="ISB"></option>
        <option value="Pencil" data-value="KHI"></option>
        <option value="Paper" data-value="PWH"></option>
        
    </datalist>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
```